# Codeigniter Table Class Vertical Display

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Using codeigniter 3, I am retrieving a single row from a MySQL database, this is in an array called `$tableData` in the following format;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 102
            [firstname] => Ross
            [lastname] => Bing
            [title] => Doctor
            [timestamp] => 2019-01-18 10:17:05
            [member_no] => 234
        )

)
```

Using the [CI table library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html) How can I display this in a vertical table like this;

```
+---------------+---------------------+
| id            | 102                 |
+---------------+---------------------+
| First Name    | Ross                |
+---------------+---------------------+
| Last Name     | Bing                |
+---------------+---------------------+
| Title         | Doctor              |
+---------------+---------------------+
| Timestamp     | 2019-01-18 10:17:05 |
+---------------+---------------------+
| Member Number | 234                 |
+---------------+---------------------+
```

My PHP

```
foreach($tableData as $row) { 
    $this->table->add_row($row);
}

$data = array(
    'table' =>  $this->table->generate()
);
```

In my view I `echo $table` and the data is displayed successfully -  but it's horizontal :/

Comment: What do you want it to look like if there is more than one "row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this can work.

```
$heading = array(
  'id' => 'custom name',
  'firstname' => 'custom name',
  'lastname' => 'custom name',
  'title' => 'custom name',
  'timestamp' => 'custom name',
  'member_no' => 'custom name'
);

$fields = array_keys($tableData[0]);
$rows = array();
foreach($fields as $key => $field) {
   $rows[$key][0] = $heading[$field];
   foreach($tableData as $key2 => $item) { 
        $rows[$key][$key2 +1] = $item[$field];
   }
}

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $this->table->add_row($row);
}

$data = array(
    'table' =>  $this->table->generate()
);
```

Comment: if you dont need array keys, comment $rows[$key][0] = $field; 
and overwrite $rows[$key][$key2 +1] = $item[$field]; to $rows[$key][$key2] = $item[$field];

Logic is simple, it builds a array where on each row contains all data from especific field from all members (first complete foreach)

I you need member_num on header, build a first row with it:

Comment: $rows[$key][0] = $heading[$field];

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)